# how to open a specific web links in flutter app,just like amazone and other e commerce sites do

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'm creating a flutter app with woocomerce as backend.an like small version of amazon
but I'm stuck on sharing products to persons through a link an when opening that link it should open app and navigate to the specific product.
I have searched a lot and found deep linking but as i know its not possible to connect every product link to a deep link service.is there is any alternative ways to do? anyone know please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with flutter web to share link to a person and open up web exactly that page. i have been working on this project for last 6 months and this is exactly what i achieved.

This can be achieved with a package called [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) on `pub.dev`.
[link](https://gorouter.dev/) for official documentation.

working demo: https://wesell.co.in/sms/product/432022100357_447202294716_8488027477

(yes this is build with flutter(canvaskit render) and hosted on apache server.)

Comment: but bro i cant find how a specific link like "amazon.com\product_id" opens in my application

Comment: go_router is a router package which directly opens a page that you specify in url